# Google Contacts API

Tags: c#, .net, google-api, google-oauth, google-contacts-api

I just started working with the google contacts api and can´t find an example how to work with the authentification stuff.

I used the [Google Contacts API version 3.0](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/contacts/v3/) documentation for understanding the basic workflow with the contacts API, but I have no idea how to work with the authentification tokens.

After some searching in the web I found the tutorial [Google OAuth2 C#](http://www.daimto.com/google-oauth2-csharp/) but in this tutorial they are working with the `UserCredential` object. In the Google Contacts API version 3.0 documentation they used the `RequestSettings` object. This object has a constructor that accepts a ApplicationName and a `GDataCredentials` object.

So I tried the following code:

```
GDataCrendentials credentials = new GDataCredentials(CLIENTID);
credentials.Username = "<my gmail username>";
this._requestSettings = new RequestSettings(GetApplicationName, _credentials);
```

The ClientId I got from the second link I posted.

So I tried to access my contacts with the code:

```
Feed<Google.Contacts.Contact> f = _contactsRequest.GetContacts();
IList<IContact> mappedContacts = new List<IContact>();

foreach (var contact in f.Entries)
{
    //do some stuff with it
}
```

With this code I get an Google.GData.Client.GDataRequestException at the foreach:

> {"Execution of request failed: https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full"}

Could you please give me a suggestion what is wrong here?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/guide/aaa_oauth

Comment: I also checked this, but the problem is that I need for the contact  API an GDataCrendentials object and not a UserCredentials object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an OAuth2 sample included with the GData .NET client library:

https://code.google.com/p/google-gdata/source/browse/trunk/clients/cs/samples/oauth2_sample/oauth2demo.cs

The relevant source code is located here:

https://code.google.com/p/google-gdata/source/browse/trunk/clients/cs/src/core/oauthutil.cs#200

Comment: I think the google api sdk may have moved here: https://github.com/google/google-api-dotnet-client